# CSV to JSON Without The array_combine()

Tags: php

Need your help with this "echo" issue... When I try to echo the **json_encode()**, it doesn't seem to work when I know the array has information.

I am truly also trying to stay away from having to use the array_combine function.

But every time I run the last json_encode function, it doesn't want to produce my end result.

```
<?php

header('Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate');
header('Content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8');

$file = 'Opportunities.csv';
$handle = fopen($file, "r");
if ($handle !== FALSE) {
    $csvs           = [];
    $headers        = [];
    $oppertunities  = [];
    while(! feof($handle)) {
        $csvs[] = fgetcsv($handle);
    }
    foreach ($csvs[0] as $single_csv) {
        $headers[] = $single_csv;
    }
    foreach ($csvs as $key => $csv) {
        if ($key === 0) {
            continue;
        }
        foreach ($headers as $header_key => $header) {
            $opportunities[$key-1][$header] = $csv[$header_key];
        }
    }
    fclose($handle);
    
    print_r($headers);                // This works
    print_r($opportunities);          // This works
    echo json_encode($headers);       // This works
    echo json_encode($opportunities); // Does NOT work, Why?
}

?>
```

> print_r($headers);// Works!

```
Array
(
    [0] => NoticeId
    [1] => Title
    [2] => Sol#
    [3] => Department/Ind.Agency
    [4] => CGAC
    [5] => Sub-Tier
    [6] => FPDS Code
    [7] => Office
    [8] => AAC Code
    [9] => PostedDate
    [10] => Type
    [11] => BaseType
    [12] => ArchiveType
    [13] => ArchiveDate
    [14] => SetASideCode
    [15] => SetASide
    [16] => ResponseDeadLine
    [17] => NaicsCode
    [18] => ClassificationCode
    [19] => PopStreetAddress
    [20] => PopCity
    [21] => PopState
    [22] => PopZip
    [23] => PopCountry
    [24] => Active
    [25] => AwardNumber
    [26] => AwardDate
    [27] => Award$
    [28] => Awardee
    [29] => PrimaryContactTitle
    [30] => PrimaryContactFullname
    [31] => PrimaryContactEmail
    [32] => PrimaryContactPhone
    [33] => PrimaryContactFax
    [34] => SecondaryContactTitle
    [35] => SecondaryContactFullname
    [36] => SecondaryContactEmail
    [37] => SecondaryContactPhone
    [38] => SecondaryContactFax
    [39] => OrganizationType
    [40] => State
    [41] => City
    [42] => ZipCode
    [43] => CountryCode
    [44] => AdditionalInfoLink
    [45] => Link
    [46] => Description
)
```

> print_r($opportunities);// Works!

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [NoticeId] => 3t54654tyj54ty1gh5
            [Title] => Solicitation for Services Contractor Level
            [Sol#] => 72MC1023R00002
            [Department/Ind.Agency] => AGENCY FOR DEVELOPMENT
            [CGAC] => 72
            [Sub-Tier] => AGENCY FOR DEVELOPMENT
            [FPDS Code] => 7200
            [Office] => USAID M/CIO
            [AAC Code] => 72MC10
            [PostedDate] => 48:44.6
            [Type] => Combined Synopsis/Solicitation
            [BaseType] => Combined Synopsis/Solicitation
            [ArchiveType] => auto15
            [ArchiveDate] => 5/15/2023
            [SetASideCode] => 
            [SetASide] => 
            [ResponseDeadLine] => 2023-04-30T11:00:00-04:00
            [NaicsCode] => 541990
            [ClassificationCode] => R497
            [PopStreetAddress] => 
            [PopCity] => Washington
            [PopState] => DC
            [PopZip] => 20523
            [PopCountry] => USA
            [Active] => Yes
            [AwardNumber] => 
            [AwardDate] => 
            [Award$] => 
            [Awardee] => 
            [PrimaryContactTitle] => 
            [PrimaryContactFullname] => first name last name
            [PrimaryContactEmail] => name@email.com
            [PrimaryContactPhone] => 2029162947
            [PrimaryContactFax] => 
            [SecondaryContactTitle] => 
            [SecondaryContactFullname] => 
            [SecondaryContactEmail] => 
            [SecondaryContactPhone] => 
            [SecondaryContactFax] => 
            [OrganizationType] => OFFICE
            [State] => DC
            [City] => WASHINGTON
            [ZipCode] => 20523
            [CountryCode] => USA
            [AdditionalInfoLink] => 
            [Link] => https://somelink.com/index.php
            [Description] => Some text....
        )
```

```
> echo json_encode($headers)// Works!
```

```
[
"NoticeId",
"Title",
"Sol#",
"Department/Ind.Agency",
"CGAC",
"Sub-Tier",
"FPDS Code",
"Office",
"AAC Code",
"PostedDate",
"Type",
"BaseType",
"ArchiveType",
"ArchiveDate",
"SetASideCode",
"SetASide",
"ResponseDeadLine",
"NaicsCode",
"ClassificationCode",
"PopStreetAddress",
"PopCity",
"PopState",
"PopZip",
"PopCountry",
"Active",
"AwardNumber",
"AwardDate",
"Award$",
"Awardee",
"PrimaryContactTitle",
"PrimaryContactFullname",
"PrimaryContactEmail",
"PrimaryContactPhone",
"PrimaryContactFax",
"SecondaryContactTitle",
"SecondaryContactFullname",
"SecondaryContactEmail",
"SecondaryContactPhone",
"SecondaryContactFax",
"OrganizationType",
"State",
"City",
"ZipCode",
"CountryCode",
"AdditionalInfoLink",
"Link",
"Description"
]
```

```
> echo json_encode($opportunities); // Does NOT work, Why?
```

I'm trying to make it look like the following:

```
{
    "0": {
            "NoticeId":"3t54654tyj54ty1gh5",
            "Title":"Solicitation for Services Contractor Level",
            "Sol#":"72MC1023R00002",
            "Department/Ind.Agency":"AGENCY FOR DEVELOPMENT",
            "CGAC":"72",
            "Sub-Tier":"AGENCY FOR DEVELOPMENT",
            "FPDS Code":"7200",
            "Office":"USAID M/CIO",
            "AAC Code":"72MC10",
            "PostedDate":"48:44.6",
            "Type":"Combined Synopsis/Solicitation",
            "BaseType":"Combined Synopsis/Solicitation",
            "ArchiveType":"auto15",
            "ArchiveDate":"5/15/2023",
            "SetASideCode":"",
            "SetASide":"",
            "ResponseDeadLine":"2023-04-30T11:00:00-04:00",
            "NaicsCode":"541990",
            "ClassificationCode":"R497",
            "PopStreetAddress":"",
            "PopCity":"Washington",
            "PopState":"DC",
            "PopZip":"20523",
            "PopCountry":"USA",
            "Active":"Yes",
            "AwardNumber":"",
            "AwardDate":"",
            "Award$":"",
            "Awardee":"",
            "PrimaryContactTitle":"",
            "PrimaryContactFullname":"first name last name",
            "PrimaryContactEmail":"name@email.com",
            "PrimaryContactPhone":"1234567890",
            "PrimaryContactFax":"",
            "SecondaryContactTitle":"",
            "SecondaryContactFullname":"",
            "SecondaryContactEmail":"",
            "SecondaryContactPhone":"",
            "SecondaryContactFax":"",
            "OrganizationType":"OFFICE",
            "State":"DC",
            "City":"WASHINGTON",
            "ZipCode":"20523",
            "CountryCode":"USA",
            "AdditionalInfoLink":"https://somelink.com/index.php",
            "Link":"",
            "Description":"Some text...."
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to also show us the "not working" `json_encode($opportunities)` as well as what you expect that it should be.

Comment: What do you get from json_last_error()?

Comment: Warning:  json_last_error() expects exactly 0 parameters, 1 given in index.php on line 48